# Is there a way to output debug messages in Perl that are not piped?

Tags: perl, pipe

Is there a way to output debug messages in Perl that are not piped? I have a Perl script that I use in a pipe but I really want to print some diagnostic information to the screen instead of to the pipe.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Are you piping both stdout and stderr? If not, write to the one you're not piping :)

e.g.

```
print STDERR "This goes to standard error";
print STDOUT "This goes to standard output";
```

(If you don't provide a handle, STDOUT is the default of course - unless you've asked Perl to use a *different* default handle...)

Comment: STDOUT is only the default if you have not used select to tell Perl a different handle should be the default.  It is the default default if you will.

Comment: You forgot the semi-colons, this isn't python.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you have said something like `2>&1` on the commandline, STDERR should show up on the screen.  You can write to STDERR like Jon Skeet [suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/746489/output-text-that-is-not-piped-in-perl/746496#746496) or you can use the [`warn`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/warn.html) function.